# Cucumber Parallel execution -Single Scenario with multiple data

Tags: parameters, parallel-processing, cucumber

I have a cucumber framework.I Want to run the same step definition class parallel in two different chrome browsers with different input passed.So how to pass the different input parameter ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your issue, is it about parallel execution, passing parameters from a feature file to a stepdef method, or using the same stepdef method in different contexts (browsers) ?

Comment: @LoïcLeDoyen :I want to execute the same definition file with different input passed.Same definition class should be running in different thread.

Thread 1-StepDefinition class(input value1)-chrome1
Thread2-Stepdefinition class(input value2)-chrome2

Comment: It not Cucumber's forte to run stuff in parallel especially what seems to be in your case different **Examples** of a same **ScenarioOutline** (as Reporter is not thread safe). For running in parallel, people tend to copy/paste to another feature file, the almost same scenario so they can be run in parallel.